# Delay response of get request using Node.js

Tags: node.js, get, xmlhttprequest

I am using an XMLHttpRequest dependency that works basically like the one in web JavaScript. However, I am trying to create an API on it that allows me to read specific data on a page. The page doesn't load completely by the time the get request is finished so the still loading items (which load in like a few milliseconds) don't appear in the response text, meaning the API wont work and be able to read the data.

```js
console.log((await HTTPGetPromise('https://www.roblox.com/users/1/profile')).match(/<\s*?li\s+?class="\s*?accoutrement-item\s*?"\s+?ng-non-bindable=""\s*?>(.+)/i));
```

Where HTTPGetPromise just returns the response text from the resulting request (and its asynchronous.) When I check the match on the actual site (using document.body.innerHTML,) it does in fact return something during the match but in Node.js it just returns `null`

This has been a large issue for many things I tried to make such as an inventory reader or outfit searcher.

This is my definition of the function.

```js
/**
 * Performs a get request using promises
 * @param {string} url The url to get
 * @returns {Promise<string>} The resulting promise
 */
const HTTPGetPromise = url => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.responseText);
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send();
    });
};
```

Is there any reliable way to delay the response so that everything can finish loading?

Comment: What does "finish loading" mean?  Finish loading into what?  When `xhr.onload` triggers, the xmlhttprequest is done and all data that's ever going to be there should be there.  It is possible that the content you want is not actually present in the raw http response, but is instead something that is inserted via Javascript or iframes or something like that.  So, there is nothing to "wait" for when making an http request.  The response is the response and waiting won't make more content appear in the response.

Comment: If you're comparing to what a browser will see, that's a whole different animal.  The browser runs Javascript (which may be fetching other content and inserting it in the page), it loads other resources (images, frames, etc...).  If you want to end up with what the browser shows, then you will need something like a headless browser like PhantomJS or others.  They try to simulate a whole browser environment in your node.js app and will parse the pages, run Javascript, load other content, etc...

Comment: do you guys know of any ways i can simulate the browser then pull a get request / get the source from that then? or do you know how i can get to this? [Sources => profile](https://i.gyazo.com/b698acc4bb54784cb426d7f30951cf6e.png) using get/post?

Comment: nvm ignore that, first question only.

Comment: I gave you a recommendation already (PhantomJS and there are others too).  The idea is that you download the page with a get request, you give it to the headless browser and it does its thing to load the rest of the page, run Javscript, etc...  You then get a browser DOM-like object that you can query to see the resulting content when it's finished.